# Java: saved settings with Preferences not restored when a GUI application starts

Tags: java, singleton, preferences

In my Java app, I have a number of saved values and settings that I would like to get as soon as the application starts. All these values are supposed to be stored in a singleton.
For example, I have a JDialog, where I save a path to my file using this:

```
AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance( );
private Preferences prefs;

private void btnSetPanelSetNavdataActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      

        appSingleton.setNavdataPath(txtNavdataPath.getText());

        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
        prefs.put("NAVDATA_PATH", txtNavdataPath.getText());

        dispose();
}
```

I am checking and the value is saved.

This is my singleton:

```
public class AppSingleton 
{

    private static AppSingleton instance = null;   
    private String navdataPath = "";

    private AppSingleton() 
    {

    }

    public static AppSingleton getInstance() 
    {
        if(instance == null) 
        {
            instance = new AppSingleton();
        }
      return instance;
    }

    public String getNavdataPath() {
        return navdataPath;
    }

    public void setNavdataPath(String navdataPath) {
        this.navdataPath = navdataPath;
    }


    public void initDefaultValues()
    {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
        this.navdataPath = prefs.get("NAVDATA_PATH","");

        System.out.printf("CHECK DEFAULT: %s",this.navdataPath);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the saved values from the main() method in the class that initializes the JFrame:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() {
                new IGAMainFrame().setVisible(true);

                /* HERE!!! */
                AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance();
                appSingleton.initDefaultValues();
            }
        });
}
```

But the values are not initialized from the Preference class. "CHECK DEFAULT" shows empty string. I do not understand why and whether there is a better practice of restoring all saved values when a GUI application starts.

Thanks!

Comment: CHECK DEFAULT is empty string because the default value you are providing is "" (Empty String). One question for you is which class is the first block of code in. Are you sure this.getClass().getName() is same while saving and retrieving. You have not mentioned the class in which the first block of code exists.

Comment: Just wondering, where are you supposed to call `btnSetPanelSetNavdataActionPerformed()` ?

Comment: The button, the main() method and the singleton are three different classes.

Comment: Change the line `prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());` inside `btnSetPanelSetNavdataActionPerformed` to `prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(Appsingleton.class.getName());` Inside button click method, `this.getClass()` is not `AppSingleton`

Comment: If that's the case won't the node path be different when saving and retrieving??

Comment: @svasa. It actually did help!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());` inside `btnSetPanelSetNavdataActionPerformed` to `prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(Appsingleton.class.getName());` Inside button click method, `this.getClass()` is not `AppSingleton`